# Compare two layers and just select the unequal datasets

Tags: qgis

I have two layer (lineshapes from OSM) with the same attributenames. But one of the layer includes more datasets. Now I want to create a query that compares both attributetables and put out/ select only the unequal datasets. So i want to get a atributetable with all the datesets, which not included in both shapes.

But i don't know how to do it, because the atributename in both layer are the same.

for example:
the first atributetable includes 110000 datasets.
the second atributetable includes 130000 datasets.

So i want two compare the atribute "osm_id" in both layer. the result should be all osm_id's which just include in one of the layer.

Comment: When you "want to create" that query, why don't you do it ? What is the problem ? That should be part of the question. Also more details should be included like what is the data format/source and much more. And of course also what did you  try so far to achieve the intended result.

Comment: my problem is that i don´t know how to do it. should i join both layer layer at first? both of the layer are lineshapes from osm

Comment: please edit the question and add any relevant information.

Comment: @user100002 - If both datasets contain similar geometries (i.e. `osm_id` for both layers are the exact same in terms of attributes and physical shape), you could run the **Difference** tool.

Comment: hi Joseph, yes they are. Thank you, but I think i isnt't so easy. I've found the following Question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/243981/qgis-difference-between-polygon-layers

I think that I will have probably  the same troubles.